# Android 13 when using overridePendingTransition exitAnim does not work

Tags: android, android-animation, android-13

overridePendingTransition only works for enterAnim but not exitAnim when I upgrade my device to Android 13.

My app is using below approach,and Activity B exit animation works in all os version except Android 13.

Activity A -> Activity B -> (FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TOFRONT) Activity A

Activity B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.push_bottom_out);
```

Activity A:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.push_bottom_out);
}
```

push_bottom_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="80%p"
        android:duration="300"/>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0.3"
        android:duration="300" />
</set>
```